# Is is possible to separate javafx ui files?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm creating an app with javafx and I want to separate ui files.
Like: Tabs in separate file and just import and create new Tab in main app.

I have tried it, but when I try to set it on main app like `borderPane.setCenter(tabPane);` it says that `The method setCenter(Node) in the type BorderPane is not applicable for the arguments (Tabs)`

Main.java app code

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import utils.Tabs;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 250, Color.WHITE);
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        Tabs tabs = new Tabs();

        // bind to take available space
        borderPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
        borderPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());

        borderPane.setCenter(tabs);

        root.getChildren().add(borderPane);
        window.setTitle("Computer Security — Demos");
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Tabs.java

```java
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class Tabs extends TabPane {

    public Tabs() {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        Tab tab = new Tab("Tab: ");
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Tab"));
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tab.setContent(hbox);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Tabs` class is not a subclass of [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html). The argument to method `setCenter()` must be a subclass of `Node`.

Comment: @abra When I extend `TabPane` there is no error bu at the same time nothing shows on GUI if I `extends Node` is not working

Comment: [edit] your question and post the code that does compile, so that I can copy it and run it and try to help you resolve your issue.

Comment: It is done. I have edited with latest changes. :)

Comment: With `Tabs` extending `TabPane` you should be adding each `Tab` to the instance itself. You're currently adding them to a `TabPane` you instantiate in the constructor but then do nothing with.

Comment: A general rule (not related to your problem): don't extend concrete controls (like TabPane) if you can reach the same goal by configuration - your Tabs adds no functionality, but just configures.